# WSO2 Enterprise Store vs Governance Registry

Tags: registry, wso2, wso2-es, wso2-governance-registry

I want to explore a couple of wso2 products, before that I want to get a clear idea of scenarios where Wso2 governance registry and Wso2 Enterprise store are used.

However, I find the features of both these products very similar. So I require a better understanding. Could anyone help?

Some use cases to understand these different products will really help.

Comment: you might want to contact wso2 to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 ES provides a way to create, publish, manage digital assets.Say for example you need to have a app store similar to Google play or e-commerce platform like Amazon in that case you can extend/customize WSO2 ES according to your requirement.

Governance aspects of any enterprise can be handled though WSO2 GREG. For example even WSO2 ES internally uses GREG to store asset meta data, manage life-cycle etc..

Hope following links might help to differentiate these two products further

http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-store/

http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/